# Container managed security in Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have followed this blog-tutorial and successfully got it to work:
http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html

I have named my two entities `Group` and `User`. The have a bi-directional many-to-many relationship.
Now the reason I have done it as in the blog is because I am making an administrator page where I want to be able to add new users. I also let users have the oppertunity to register them self, and they will have the role `user`.

```
    @Entity
    public class Group implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String groupName;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="group_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id")})
        private List<User> users;

       ....

}
```

and

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "app_user")
    public class User implements Serializable {

        public static final String ALL = "User.all";

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private Integer age;
        private String username;
        private String email;
        private String password;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
        private List<Group> groups;

        ....
}
```

My question is how I would assign the group `user` to a user when it register without me picking the groups from a list in the view?

This is what I have done in the application code but it binds the code the the id of the group in the database, are there better ways?

Method from EJB

```
public void persistAsUser(User user) {
    Group group = new Group(2L, "user");
    user.addGroup(group);

    userRepository.persist(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to define a UNIQUE index on the field groupName. Then, create a Data Access Object for the Group table, which provides a method for getting a Group from a groupName (code not tested):

```
public class GroupDAO implements Serializable {
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;
    public Group findByGroupName(String groupName) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Group> cq = cb.createQuery(Group.class);
        Root<Group> group = cq.from(Group.class);
        cq.where(cb.equal(group.get(Group_.groupName), groupName));
        TypedQuery<Group> q = em.createQuery(cq);
        return q.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

---

If you don't like Criteria Builder, you can use a Named Query. Add this annotation to your Group Entity Class:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Group.findByGroupname", query = "SELECT f FROM group f WHERE f.groupname = :groupname")
```

and build a Named Query as follows:

```
return em.createNamedQuery("Group.findByGroupname").setParameter("groupname", groupName).getResultList();
```